# neo4j find predefined subgraph in undirected and unweighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, cypher

I want to find all possible predefined combinations in a graph.

What that means: In the following diagram I have to answer how many movies Tom Cruise participated and the counts of all possible directors and all possible co actors.

So let's say the input is this diagram:

[image]

After running the algorithm, the answer is:
Tom Cruise participates in 41 movies. 
These 41 movies were directed by 35 distinct directors.
In these 41 movies, Tom Cruise has 275 distinct co-actors

[image]

This is relatively simple. I can do it with 3 matches. First I will take all possible Cruise's movies and their count. And next I will execute matches for links count between those movies in the result and directors and than the same with the actors.

My problems begin when someone add 2 or more known nodes. For example let's say that someone search connection between Tom Cruise and True Romance trough the diagram. In other words he looks for Movies with Tom Cruise and directed by the True Romance's director. So he adds a new known movie and connects it to unknown director.

So now we run the algorithm again. Here my algorithm will start from Tom Cruise and will do the matches and will count movies, and directors until it finds that the director has to be director also of True Romance. Now It has to back trace all the matches and recalculate their counts accordingly. 
In the example the answer of the new input is: director of True Romance is Tony Scott , a single match, and he also directed 2 movies with Tom Cruise - "Top Gun" and "Days of thunder". And there is 7 actors that participated in these movies.

[image]

The things can get even more complicated when there are a circular routes like:

[image]

Now I can't see how to traverse the diagram. Let say I start from known nodes but to merge the results I have to pass through every node at least 3 times because of the edge with question mark.

So is their an efficient algorithm to find all possible answers in a relatively big graph? An answer means given an input from diagram to populate the count of all possible options for the unknown nodes.

Comment: It is not very clear what the algorithm should do, what is the input etc.. e.g. why do bother with `True romance` when Tom has nothing to do with it?

Comment: Tom Cruise participated let's say in 35 movies. Directors of these films are a list of 30 directors and one of them is Tony Scott, who is director of True romance. That's what Tom Cruise and True Romance has in common.

Comment: I modified the text . Is it clearer now ?

Comment: So the input can be any 2 nodes? Actor, Movie or Director?

Comment: Yes. Even more in any moment you can choose from the unknown answer list to narrow down the results even further.  For example in the second diagram where are the answers if you choose Nicole Kidman as a co-actor movies must be filtered to Far and away, Days of thunder, Eyes wide shut and the count must be set to 3. Directors must be filtered accordingly.